# Appending blob to formData gives [TypeError: Network request failed]

Tags: react-native, form-data

I am starting to get i bit insane trying to make a simple file upload from my react-native app to my backend. if i try to send the post request without appending the file like:

```
const uploadImage = async () => {
    try {
        let formData = new FormData()
        const response = await fetch(selectedImage)
        const blob = await response.blob()
        formData.append('file', blob, 'avatar.jpg')

        let myHeaders = new Headers()
        myHeaders.append('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data')
        myHeaders.append('authorization', '11|0oEkyFmf5TtpxPbvPCEPwju95NbZIaObXdsaJJY3')
        const uploadResponse = await fetch(process.env.EXPO_PUBLIC_API_URL + '/auth/user/update', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: myHeaders,
            body: 'hello',
        })
        console.log(selectedImage)
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
}
```

eveything workis fine,and i can reach and get the response from my api, but if i try to append the blob to my formData:

```
const uploadImage = async () => {
    try {
        let formData = new FormData()
        const response = await fetch(selectedImage)
        const blob = await response.blob()
        formData.append('file', blob, 'avatar.jpg')

        let myHeaders = new Headers()
        myHeaders.append('Content-Type', 'multipart/form-data')
        myHeaders.append('authorization', '11|0oEkyFmf5TtpxPbvPCEPwju95NbZIaObXdsaJJY3')
        const uploadResponse = await fetch(process.env.EXPO_PUBLIC_API_URL + '/auth/user/update', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: myHeaders,
            body: formData,
        })
        console.log(blob)
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error)
    }
}
```

I get the [TypeError: Network request failed] error. For reference, here are some relevant data

selectedImage value:

```
file:///data/user/0/com.username.appsmobile/cache/ImagePicker/713638a0-89b5-4e85-a3cb-6dbfc5448dde.jpeg
```

console.log(blob) gives:

```
{"_data": {"__collector": {}, "blobId": "83c299f5-26df-4a32-bd05-46f96d158f2a", "lastModified": 0, "name": "713638a0-89b5-4e85-a3cb-6dbfc5448dde.jpeg", "offset": 0, "size": 479879, "type": "image/jpeg"}}
```

Comment: don't set Content-Type header... FormData will automatically add that header.  Assuming that the blob is a blob (though it looks like JSON to me...) it should work.  It's easier to just add the form element... so new FormData(your_form_webelement);